# How can I most easily flatten a three-dimensional array in Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Say I have an array such as this:

```
NSArray *threeDimensionalArray = @[
 @[     
     @[ @"Peter", @"Paul", @"Mary" ], @[ @"Joe", @"Jane" ]
  ],
 @[
     @[ @"Alice", @"Bob" ]
  ]
];
```

and I want it to become:

```
@[ @"Peter", @"Paul", @"Mary", @"Joe", @"Jane", @"Alice", @"Bob" ]
```

How can I most easily create this flattened array?

Comment: +1 for both the question and the answer, elegant solution.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The key-value coding (KVC) collection operator `@unionOfArrays` flattens one level of arrays, so applying it twice produces the desired result.

Collection operators (other than `@count`) need a key path to a collection property, and since our objects are already arrays (and hence collections) in themselves, the key path will have to be `self`.

We therefore need to  apply `@unionOfArrays` twice with the `self` key path, yielding the following KVC call to flatten a 3D array:

```
NSArray *flattenedArray = [threeDimensionalArray valueForKeyPath: @"@unionOfArrays.self.@unionOfArrays.self"];
```

Comment: For the OP's later refined question - flattening arbitrary-level array hierarchy, you could do { flatten } while (output doesn't contain an NSArray) or some better halt condition. KVC could help here too with [[currentArray valueForKeyPath:@"class"] containsObject:[NSArray class]]

Answer (score 2):

I realize this thread is a little bit old, but I needed a solution where the number of levels deep doesn't really matter. The following methods could be added to a category on NSArray. I've also included the test for these methods:

```
// This is the method that would be used from an outside class
- (NSArray *)flatten {
    NSArray *array = self;
    while (![array isFlattened]) {
        array = [array flattenOneLevel];
    }
    return [NSArray arrayWithArray:array];
}

- (NSArray *)flattenOneLevel {
    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (id object in self) {
        [object isKindOfClass:self.class] ? [array addObjectsFromArray:object] : [array addObject:object];
    }
    return array;
}

- (BOOL)isFlattened {
    BOOL flattened = YES;
    for (id object in self) {
        if ([object isKindOfClass:self.class]) {
            flattened = NO;
            break;
        }
    }
    return flattened;
}
```

Here's the test for these methods to ensure it works properly:

```
it(@"should flatten an array", ^{
    NSArray *initialArray = @[@[@23, @354, @1, @[@7], @[@[@3]]], @[@[@890], @2, @[@[@6], @8]]];
    NSArray *expectedArray = @[@23, @354, @1, @7, @3, @890, @2, @6, @8];
    expect([initialArray flatten]).equal(expectedArray);
});
```

Comment: Two issues here. One - this is very inefficient. you re-scan the same elements again and again every "flattenOneLevel" pass, and you scan AGAIN the same elements, to see if you're flat already... Second issue - you look for exact class as the container - which is wrong. you better ask for [object isKindOfClass:[NSArray class] ]

Answer (score 2):

An alternative answer using recursion, which will take more memory (on the stack), but for those who like recursion, is simpler to read:

```
- (NSArray *) flatten;
{
    NSMutableArray *flattedArray = [NSMutableArray new];

    for (id item in self) {
        if ([[item class] isSubclassOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
            [flattedArray addObjectsFromArray:[item flatten]];
        } else {
            [flattedArray addObject:item];
        }
    }

    return flattedArray;
}
```

And extending the tests:

```
+ (void) unitTests;
{
    NSArray *flattenedArray;

    NSArray *initialArray1 = @[@[@23, @354, @1, @[@7], @[@[@3]]], @[@[@890], @2, @[@[@6], @8]]];
    NSArray *expectedArray1 = @[@23, @354, @1, @7, @3, @890, @2, @6, @8];
    flattenedArray = [initialArray1 flatten];
    SPASLogDetail(@"flattenedArray: %@", flattenedArray);
    AssertIf(![flattenedArray isEqualToArray:expectedArray1], @"Arrays are not equal");

    NSArray *initialArray2 = @[@[@23, @354, @1, [@[@7] mutableCopy], @[@[@3]]], @[[@[@890] mutableCopy], @2, @[@[@6], @8]]];
    NSArray *expectedArray2 = expectedArray1;
    flattenedArray = [initialArray2 flatten];
    SPASLogDetail(@"flattenedArray: %@", flattenedArray);
    AssertIf(![flattenedArray isEqualToArray:expectedArray2], @"Arrays are not equal");
}
```

Comment: This serves arbitrary hierarchy which is nicer than other answers. Question is - how to "unroll" recursion here and turn it to stacked enumeration...

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but reading all the answers here (some are beautiful) I thought there's still something to be desired.

The OPs question was about a hard 3-level NSArray of NSStrings, but I think he later hinted he was after an arbitrary-level solution.

All the answers attending to this - suffer noticeable inefficiency. Recursion may be heavy on the stack and heap, while non-recursive code here re-scanned the items again and again...

So here is my take on it (tested and works for the test arrays in above answers.

```
NSArray *threeDimensionalArray = @[
 @[   @[ @"Peter", @"Paul", @"Mary" ], @[ @"Joe", @"Jane" ] ],
 @[   @[ @"Alice", @"Bob" ] ] ];
NSArray *expectedArray = @[ @"Peter", @"Paul", @"Mary", @"Joe", @"Jane", @"Alice", @"Bob" ];

NSMutableArray *flatArray = [NSMutableArray new];
NSMutableArray *containers = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:threeDimensionalArray, nil];
do {
    NSArray *currArray = [containers firstObject];
    [containers removeObjectAtIndex:0];
    for (id item in currArray) {
        if ([item isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
            [containers addObject:item];
        else
            [flatArray addObject:item];
    }
} while (containers.count > 0);

if ([flatArray isEqualToArray:expectedArray])
    NSLog(@"flattened correctly");
```

This one only passes each item once (except for the contained arrays which are passed twice). No recursion, and relatively concise implementation.

I think it can be done faster by using better enumeration than for...in but that's for another time.