# Handling unnamed arrays with RestKit

Tags: objective-c, json, restkit

I need to be able to read some JSON that I no control over. Basically the JSON looks like this:

```
[ [{"a":1,"b":2}], [{"a":1,"b":2}], [{"a":1,"b":2}] ]
```

I'm trying to parse it with RestKit and I just couldn't figure out how to handle the first two levels of the object hierarchy. The items in question are more complicated but they are not the issue here. The issue is how should I skip the second array that empirically would seem to have only one item every time.

In short, I'd like to flatten this and get single array instead of an array of arrays.

I've tried to create a mapping for `NSArray`but from there I have no idea how to map the items in this array. The inner array has no name and I couldn't figure out how to reference it in the mappings.

Any working solution is greatly appreciated.

### Update

The issue here is **how should I create the JSON mappings** and not how to read multi-dimensional arrays. I've tried the following but I don't know if the mapping for `NSArray` is ok. The following mapping gives an example, but it doesn't work:

```
secondMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[MyClass class]];
[secondMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
 @"a": @"a",
 @"b": @"b"
 }];

firstMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[NSArray class]];
[firstMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:nil
                                                                              toKeyPath:nil
                                                                             withMapping:secondMapping]];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I most easily flatten a three-dimensional array in Cocoa?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17109942/how-can-i-most-easily-flatten-a-three-dimensional-array-in-cocoa)

Comment: This is not about handling the data structures. I can't make the mappings work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to make this work without giving up on RestKit was to add a custom JSON serializer. I only needed the `secondMapping` and mappings from there on required to match the object hierarchy.

```
[RKMIMETypeSerialization registerClass:[MySerialization class] forMIMEType:@"application/json"];
```

And here is my serializer:

```
@implementation MySerialization

+ (id)objectFromData:(NSData *)data error:(NSError **)error
{
    id object = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:error];
    // Fix the following weirdness in JSON response:
    // [ [{route_1}], ..., [{route_n}] ]
    if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]
        && [[object lastObject] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
    {
        object = [object valueForKeyPath:@"@unionOfArrays.@self"];
    }
    return object;
}

+ (NSData *)dataFromObject:(id)object error:(NSError **)error
{
    return [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:object options:0 error:error];
}

@end
```

Other alternative is block in `RKResponseMapperOperation` mentioned [here](http://restkit.org/api/latest/Classes/RKResponseMapperOperation.html#//api/name/setWillMapDeserializedResponseBlock%3a)

```
- (void)setWillMapDeserializedResponseBlock:(id ( ^ ) ( id deserializedResponseBody ))block
```

I chose the custom serializer as it was simpler, but this is definitely more scalable way.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just copy over the single element of the inner arrays to another array?

```
NSMutableArray *newArr = [NSMutableArray new];
for (NSArray *innerArr in jsonObject)
    [newArr addObject:innerArr[0]];
```

Comment: Sorry for being vague but I meant that the mappings were the issue. Parsing the data is a non-issue once I can map the data properly.

Comment: @mkko and that's exactly what this answer is a solution for.

Comment: Where can I get the jsonObject? As stated above, I'm using RestKit.

Comment: @mkko You said parsing was trivial? You use `NSJSONSerialization`.

Comment: Sorry, I meant parsing the data as opposed to parsing the JSON. The JSON here is the issue. I'd like to use RestKit as it provides some convenience over network access and caching.

Comment: @mkko sorry for my ignorance, but last time I saw RestKit it could auto-parse JSON. Is this not anymore the case?

Comment: That exactly is the question here. I'd like to use the mappings provided by the RestKit but I couldn't figure out how. RestKit reads the JSON indeed, but mapping it with the unnamed arrays isn't that trivial to me.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what you're trying to map to, it will be a little difficult to map the base dictionary into a custom object. If you create an object with an array property:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *items;
```

Then you can map an array of these objects where the `items` array will contain `NSDictionary` instances. This would use a `nil` keypath to map to the `items` key.

Comment: I tried this but the `nil` keypath was not ok for RestKit. Do you have any examples with code?

Comment: I don't think you can do it the way your mappings are structured. It would need to be the other way around with the custom class holding an array and the `NSDictionary` instances mapped into that. You should really change the JSON...

Comment: Yeah, I ended up changing the JSON DOM after it was parsed as I have no control over the JSON format. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From my experience with RestKit, this will only work for ONE mapping. Use @"" as the root keypath and you should be able to get it to work. However what you probably need to do if you intend to use RestKit for your entire application is to modify the response data to include the root element name.

Comment: Right. The root element is an array, so there'd be an array of arrays then. It all comes down to modifying the response and I think it'd be cleaner to just flatten the two-dimensional representation.