# Filter Arrays in Objects using NSPredicate

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nspredicate

I need to filter an array by a property from an object that is inside another array.
Let's say that I got two classes like:

StoreList.h

```
@interface StoreList : NSObject {
  NSMutableArray *storesArray; //Array containing Store objects
}
```

Store.h

```
@interface Store : NSObject {
  NSString *name;
}
```

So, I have an NSArray (storeListArray) that have some StoreList objects in it. Then, my Array is something like this:

```
storeListArray = [
 StoreList:{
    storesArray: {
                  stores[{
                    store: {
                     name: "Store1"
                    },
                    store: {
                     name: "Store2"
                    }
                  }]
                },
    storesArray: {
                  stores[{
                    store: {
                     name: "Store1"
                    },
                    store: {
                     name: "Store2"
                    }
                  }]
                }
   }
];
```

Well, my question is: How can I filter storeListArray by the "name" property of the Store Object, using NSPredicate?

I was trying to do something like this, but this don't work:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY storeList CONTAINS[cd] %@", filterString];
self.filteredStores = [storeListArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
return self.filteredStores;
```

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
NSPredicate * predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY SELF.storesArray.name == %@", filterString];

NSArray * videoArray = [storeListArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried as like below,

```
NSPredicate * predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name == %@", filterString];

NSArray * videoArray = [storeListArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that was the first thing that I did. But it gives me the error: * Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[StoreList valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key name.'

Comment: The above would work if storeListArray contained store objects, instead of arrays of store objects. Perhaps filter each child array in a loop? Or flatten storeListArray before filtering?

Comment: @JoshuaKaden I tried doing a Loop, but can't return the filtered List. Can you please provide me some example using the flatten thing?

Comment: Sure; just check out [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17087380/flatten-an-nsarray].