# Get all values from NSMutableDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a simple `UITableView`, when users adds new rows, these will be added to the `NSMutableDictionary`. I can retrieve the values for a specific key.

```
NSArray *myArr = [myDictionary valueForKey:@"Food"];
```

This will show me all values for key food, this is an example of my NSLog:

> (
>       burger,
>       pasta )

If I add more objects to myDictionary but for a different key, for example:

```
NSArray *drinks = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"cola",@"sprite",nil];
[myDictionary setObject:drinks forKey:@"Drink"];
```

I can't retrieve all values using the following code:

```
NSArray *allMenu = [myDictionary allValues];
```

It shows me the following NSLog:

> (
>           (
>           burger,
>           past
>       ),
>           (
>           cola,
>           sprite
>       ) )

I don't know where is the problem. Why I can't get all values from `NSDictionary` to `NSArray`.

If I use the code:

```
NSArray *allMenu = [[myDictionary allValues] objectAtIndex:0];
```

will show me the Food values. If I change objectAtIndex to 1 will show me the Drink value.

Comment: What the result do you want?

Comment: Unclear question. You are getting all values into the `allMenu`.

Comment: why use allValues, use only  objectATIndex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in one line by **flattening** the returned 2-dimensional array by using key value coding ([KVC](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html)). I found this in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17087380/flatten-an-nsarray), see [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html). In your case, it looks as follows:

```
NSMutableDictionary *myDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
NSArray *food = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"burger",@"pasta",nil];
[myDictionary setObject:food forKey:@"Food"];
NSArray *drinks = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"cola",@"sprite",nil];
[myDictionary setObject:drinks forKey:@"Drink"];

NSArray *allMenue = [[myDictionary allValues] valueForKeyPath:@"@unionOfArrays.self"];
```

Answer (score 4):

I am not entirely sure what you are asking, if you are trying to print all of the values within an NSDictionary do the following:

```
//Gets an array of all keys within the dictionary
NSArray dictionaryKeys = [myDictionary allKeys];
for (NSString *key in dictionaryKeys)
{
    //Prints this key
    NSLog(@"Key = %@", key);
    //Loops through the values for the aforementioned key
    for (NSString *value in [myDictionary valueForKey:key])
    {
        //Prints individual values out of the NSArray for the key
        NSLog(@"Value = %@", value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Solution :

```
- (NSDictionary *) indexKeyedDictionaryFromArray:(NSArray *)array 
        {
          id objectInstance;
          NSUInteger indexKey = 0U;
          for (objectInstance in myArr)
            [mutableDictionary setObject:objectInstance forKey:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:indexKey++]];

          return (NSDictionary *)[myDictionary autorelease];
        }
```